# Image uploading/Cropping using asp.net/Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am working on an asp.net application. I have a page with File upload control. I want to allow user to crop/resize the image before uploading. user will select the image, it will be shown on page ( temporary upload perhaps), user will crop, click yes or discard link, and then click save button which will save the record ( with other info) and image info( size, pat, name) etc to contact table.

Do I need to use some Jquery plugin ? Please suggest.

Comment: Hi, you can use jquery.jWindowCrop.js for croping images.

Comment: you can use [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)